# kivymd screen turns black wherever mouse clicks

Tags: python, user-interface, stream, kivy, kivymd

i'm writing a music-streaming platform using a client-server architecture. on the client's side i am using the kivymd library to write the GUI. when the streaming happens the client is presented a screen that says "streaming now", and there are play and pause buttons. for some reason, when the streaming happens (works alright) and we're on the "streaming now" screen, if the user's mouse clicks anywhere on the screen, either the buttons or anywhere else, the screen just turns black. the streaming doesn't stop though even when the screen is black - the song is heard well.

this is the streaming screen's class on the client side:

```
class StreamingScreen(Screen):
global is_playing
is_playing = True

streaming_thread = None

def on_enter(self):
    self.streaming_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.play_song())
    # self.play_song()
    self.streaming_thread.start()
    print('started the thread')

def pause(self, *args):
    global is_playing
    print('pause pressed')
    is_playing = False
    # Send a pause command to the server
    client.send('PAUSE'.encode())

def resume(self):
    global is_playing
    print('resume pressed')
    is_playing = True
    # Send a resume command to the server
    client.send('RESUME'.encode())

def play_song(self):
    global is_playing

    client.send('GOOD'.encode(FORMAT))
    print('now playing song')

    # Stream song
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(2),
                    channels=2,
                    rate=44100,
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")

    while True:
        if is_playing:
            while len(data) < payload_size:
                packet = client.recv(4 * 1024)  # 4K
                if not packet:
                    break
                data += packet
            packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
            data = data[payload_size:]
            msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
            while len(data) < msg_size:
                data += client.recv(4 * 1024)
            frame_data = data[:msg_size]
            data = data[msg_size:]
            frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
            print('writing to stream')
            stream.write(frame)
        elif not is_playing:
            # Pause the stream
            print('streaming paused')
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

the kv file in charge of the streaming screen:

```
<StreamingScreen>:
name: 'streaming'

MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: '20dp'
    padding: '20dp'

    MDLabel:
        text: "Now streaming"
        font_style: "H2"
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        halign: 'center'

    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        MDFloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "arrow-left"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '72dp', '72dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                radius: [36]
                md_bg_color: (0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                    app.navigation_draw()

        MDFloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "play"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '96dp', '96dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                radius: [48]
                md_bg_color: (0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
                on_press:
                    root.play()

        MDFloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "pause"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '72dp', '72dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                radius: [36]
                md_bg_color: (0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
                on_press:
                    root.pause()
```

when i press the "pause" button, the "pause" function is not even called. something there crashes because of the mouse click and i don't understand why. any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your issue, but you are not running `play_song()` in a thread. You should use `self.streaming_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.play_song)`. Note the removal of `()` after `play_song`.